# Test the sequence of functions $x_n={e^{-nt}}$ for convergence in $C[0,1]$,$L_{1}(0,1)$ and $L_{2}(0,1)$.

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, uniform-convergence

> Test the sequence of functions $$x_n(t)={e^{-nt}}$$ for convergence in
> $C[0,1]$,$L_{1}(0,1)$ and $L_{2}(0,1)$. In case of convergence, find
> the limit function.

What I have done.

**(1)** In  $C[0,1]$

For $C[0,1]$ we have that $\lim_{n->\infty} e^{-nt}$ converges to $0$ when $0<t\leq1$, and to $1$ when $t=0$.

**Can I say, without further testing, that it diverges in $C[0,1]$, because it does not converges uniformelly?**

**(2)** In $L_{1}(0,1)$

*Point-wise convergence*: In this case, because $t \neq 0$, the sequence $$\lim_{n->\infty} e^{-nt}=0$$
when $t \in (0,1)$ is fixed. It converges point-wise on $(0,1)$

*Uniform convergence*: I computed the norm of this metric space
$$ \|x\|_{L^1} = \int_{0}^1|x(t)|\,dt =\frac{1-e^{-n}}{n} $$.

Now, the sequence $\frac{1-e^{-n}}{n} $ converges to $0$ when $n$ aproaches $\infty$, then $x_n(t)$ converges in $L_{1}(0,1)$. **How do I find the limit of the sequence?**

Comment: Concerning the first question you should add that the convergence cannot be unform as the pointwise limit is not a continuous function. Another argument could be $f_n(1/n)=e^{-1},$ hence $f_n$ does not converge uniformly to $0$ on $(0,1].$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Yes, your argument is justified.

(2) The limit is the zero function. $L^{1}$ consists of equivalence classes of functions and values at a finite number of points do not matter.

(3) is similar to (2).

Comment: Does convergence in $C[0,1]$ imply convergence in $L_1$ and $L_2$ ?

Comment: Yes, it does. @MaroonRacoon